# nhibernate 3.0 optimistic lock and related entities

Tags: nhibernate, versioning

I've noticed in my database (SQL Server) that the column I'm using for versioning is getting updated for an entity whenever that entity is added to a related table.

So, for example, if I have a `Person` entity and I add a `Person` to a `Club`, the `Person`'s record in the database will have a new version. Of course, in the database, it's the `Club`'s record that is added/updated with the `Person`'s primary key.

I'm a bit surprised by that behavior because no other data for the `Person` entity is changing.

My question is if there is a way to turn that off; that is, to only have the version column updated when data in that row changes. What might the implications of that kind of configuration be?

**EDIT** Here's the real code

Model

```
public partial class ObligationProgramFund : IMyObject
{
    private System.Int32 _id;
    // ... many other properties
    private IList<ObligationProgramFundOrganization> _obligationPFOrganizations;
    private System.Byte[] _recordVersion;

    public ObligationProgramFund() : base()
    {
        _obligationPFOrganizations = new List<ObligationProgramFundOrganization>();
    }

    public virtual System.Int32 Id
    { 
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    public virtual IList<ObligationProgramFundOrganization> ObligationPFOrganizations
    {
        get { return _obligationPFOrganizations; }
        set { _obligationPFOrganizations = value; }
    }

    public virtual System.Byte[] RecordVersion
    { 
        get { return _recordVersion; }
        set { _recordVersion = value; }
    }
}

public partial class ObligationProgramFundOrganization : IMyObject
{
    private ObligationProgramFund _obligationProgramFund;
    private System.Int32 _id;
    private Organization _organization;
    private System.Byte[] _recordVersion;
    // .. other properties

    public ObligationProgramFundOrganization() : base()
    {
    }

    public virtual System.Int32 Id
    { 
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    public virtual System.Byte[] RecordVersion
    { 
        get { return _recordVersion; }
        set { _recordVersion = value; }
    }

    public virtual ObligationProgramFund ObligationProgramFund
    {
        get { return _obligationProgramFund; }
        set { _obligationProgramFund = value; }
    }

    public virtual Organization Organization
    {
        get { return _organization; }
        set { _organization = value; }
    }
}

public partial class Organization : IMyObject
{
    private IList<ObligationProgramFundOrganization> _obligationPFOrganizations;
    private System.Int32 _id;
    private System.Byte[] _recordVersion;
    // other properties

    public Organization() : base()
    {
        _obligationPFOrganizations = new List<ObligationProgramFundOrganization>();
    }

    public virtual System.Int32 Id
    { 
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    public virtual System.Byte[] RecordVersion
    { 
        get { return _recordVersion; }
        set { _recordVersion = value; }
    }

    public virtual IList<ObligationProgramFundOrganization> ObligationPFOrganizations
    {
        get { return _obligationPFOrganizations; }
        set { _obligationPFOrganizations = value; }
    }
}
```

Mapping

```
public partial class ObligationProgramFundMap : ClassMap<ObligationProgramFund>
{
    public ObligationProgramFundMap()
    {
        Table("[MySchema2].[dbo].[ObligationProgramFund]");
        OptimisticLock.Version();
        DynamicUpdate();
        LazyLoad();

        Id(x=>x.Id)
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .Column("[Id]")
            .GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Version(x=>x.RecordVersion)
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .Column("[RecordVersion]")
                .CustomSqlType("timestamp")
                .Not.Nullable()
            .UnsavedValue("null")
            .CustomType("BinaryBlob")
            .Generated.Always();
            // other properties/components

        HasMany(x=>x.ObligationPFOrganizations)
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Fetch.Select()
            .Inverse()
            .LazyLoad()
            .KeyColumns.Add("ObligationProgramFundId"); 
        } 
    } 

public partial class ObligationProgramFundOrganizationMap : ClassMap<ObligationProgramFundOrganization>
{
    public ObligationProgramFundOrganizationMap()
    {
        Table("[MySchema2].[dbo].[ObligationProgramFundOrganization]");
        OptimisticLock.Version();
        DynamicUpdate();
        LazyLoad();

    Id(x=>x.Id)
        .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
        .Column("[Id]")
        .GeneratedBy.Identity();
    Version(x=>x.RecordVersion)
        .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
        .Column("[RecordVersion]")
            .CustomSqlType("timestamp")
            .Not.Nullable()
        .UnsavedValue("null")
        .CustomType("BinaryBlob")
        .Generated.Always();

    // other properties      

    References(x=>x.ObligationProgramFund)
        .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
        .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
        .Fetch.Select()
        .Columns("ObligationProgramFundId");
    References(x=>x.Organization)
        .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
        .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
        .Fetch.Select()
        .Columns("OrganizationId");
    } 
}

public partial class OrganizationMap : ClassMap<Organization>
{
    public OrganizationMap()
    {
        Table("[MySchema2].[dbo].[Organization]");
        OptimisticLock.Version();
        DynamicUpdate();
        LazyLoad();

        Id(x=>x.Id)
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .Column("[Id]")
            .GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Version(x=>x.RecordVersion)
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .Column("[RecordVersion]")
            .CustomSqlType("timestamp")
            .Not.Nullable()
            .UnsavedValue("null")
            .CustomType("BinaryBlob")
            .Generated.Always();

        // other properties

        HasMany(x=>x.ObligationPFOrganizations)
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Fetch.Select()
            .Inverse()
            .LazyLoad()
            .KeyColumns.Add("OrganizationId");
    } 
}
```

So my entities are

```
Organization 1 - ∞ ObligationProgramFundOrganization ∞ - 1 ObligationProgramFund
```

The issue I've observed is when a new ObligationProgramFundOrganization is created (the associative table), the record version for ObligationProgramFund is updated.

The actual senario is that I have a table of ObligationProgramFundOrganizations on the  ObligationProgramFund edit form. A ObligationProgramFundOrganization is added via AJAX calls. When I go to then save the ObligationProgramFund, I get a concurrency exception. I am sure no other user actually edited the ObligationProgramFund as it's all running locally.

Comment: That looks strange. Can a Club only have one person? That would be the only way a Club record would be updated by adding a Person. Can you post your classes and mappings?

Comment: @Diego Updated my question with real code.

Answer (score 0):

(I've posted an answer to a similar question: [Why NHibernate UPDATE reference entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331928/why-nhibernate-update-reference-entity))

You have version column specified. Which means that any property change (even collection) trigger version update.

In order to prevent a certain property/collection to change version, optimistic-lock="false" property should be set in xml mapping.