# Why NHibernate UPDATE reference entity?

Tags: nhibernate

I have a test mothod like below:

```
       public void Add_Update_Delete_a_Registration() {

        ISessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactory.GetSessionFactory(connString);
        using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession()) {

            Course course = new CourseRepository(session).GetById(12019);

            Registration entity = new Registration();
            entity.Course = course; //Assign the Course to register

            //assign other entity members
            //...

            RegistrationRepository repository = new RegistrationRepository(session);
            repository.Add(entity);
        }
```

The Registration entity was inserted correctly.

The problem is, NHibernate also made an UPDATE database call to update the Course entity which is not changed at all in the test method. What could be the possible reasons?

The mappings:

```
    public class CourseMap : ClassMap<Course>{
    public CourseMap() {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.HiLo("100");
        Map(x => x.WeekDay)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .CustomType<int>(); //WeekDay is type of DayOfWeek enums
        References(x => x.Room)
            .Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.StartTime)
            .Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.EndTime)
            .Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.CreatedTime)
            .Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.UpdatedTime);
        Map(x => x.CreatedBy)
            .Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.UpdatedBy);
        Version(x => x.Version).Column("RCB_Version")
            .CustomSqlType("timestamp")
            .Generated.Always()
            .Not.Nullable();
    }

    public class RegistrationMap : ClassMap<Registration>{
    public RegistrationMap() {
        Id(x => x.Id)
            .GeneratedBy.HiLo("100");
        Map(x => x.OwnerWindowsAccount)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Length(50);
        References(x => x.Course)
            .Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.TrainingDate)
            .Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.RegistreeName)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Length(50);
        Map(x => x.RegistreeWindowsAccount)
            .Nullable()
            .Length(50);
        Map(x => x.CreatedTime)
            .Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.UpdatedTime);
        Map(x => x.CreatedBy)
            .Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.UpdatedBy);
        Version(x => x.Version)
            .CustomSqlType("timestamp")
            .Generated.Always()
            .Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

Much appreciated!
Leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some various issues that can cause this. I often get it when I have mapped my enums wrong or is using the inverse="true|false" the wrong way.

Comment: I do have an enum property in Course mapping, which is DayOfWeek. The mapping is Map(x => x.WeekDay).Not.Nullable().CustomType<int>();. But I don't have any mapping using Inverse. I will add the mappings in my original post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have version column specified. Which means that any property change (even collection) trigger version update.

In order to prevent a certain property/collection to change version, `optimistic-lock="false"` property should be set in xml mapping.

Though not sure how it'd be in fluent syntax. Probably .OptimisticLock.False() or something.